# Unable to install atomic v1.1.13 gem via bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have tried to install atomic gem via bundler. I'm getting the below error message:

> **Installing atomic 1.1.13 with native extensions The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>       c:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>
> creating Makefile
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.13 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.13/ext/gem_make.out An
>   error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.13), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.**

Could you help me to overcome from this issue. Thanks

Comment: can give us the command you used to do such a thing

Comment: I have use the comment as **gem install atomic -v '1.1.13'** but I get the error message:  
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...  
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
The system cannot find the path specified.  
ERROR:  Error installing atomic:  
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

    c:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

Comment: All that you want is to install the gem is that right, if yes i can give tips on how to do that manually, i just tried it and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To help you here are some steps to follow in order to install your gem lacally.

1. Download  atomic 1.1.13 from RubyGems:

   - [atomic 1.1.13](https://rubygems.org/gems/atomic/versions/1.1.13)
2. Place the downloaded gem into a file called `gems`
3. Open Ruby `cmd` consol `[clic on start button, select Ruby then select  Start  command prompt with Ruby]`
4. `Cd` to the gems file path [lets supose the path of your gems file is `C:\Desktop\gems`] write the command: `cd C:\Desktop\gems`   then clic enter.
5. To install the gem run the following comand: `gem install --local atomic-1.1.13.gem`

I tried it and it worked for me, hopefuly it will work for you.

Comment: Hi, Yes I have followed your steps, But still I'm unable to install the Gem. I'm getting "ERROR:  Error installing atomic-1.1.13.gem:
                    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Comment: Is devkit installed on your machine

Comment: Yes, I have installed the dev kit ( DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx)